# Nhibernate relationship table mappings

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am using NHibernate to persist information in my media player app.  Basically at the minute I have a mapping setup for the Track class and for the Playlist class:

```
Track                      Playlist
======                     =========
Id                         Id
Name                       Name
FilePath
etc...
```

This is working fine. However now I want to create a relationship table between these 2 entities :- PlaylistTracks

```
PlaylistTracks
===============
PlaylistId
TrackId
```

The tracks that are in a playlist are held as a list of tracks in the playlist object.  My question is how do I create this mapping to get the required table strucutre

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use a [many-to-many](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-6/1nr4enxv3dpeq/9#6%282E%293%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Collections_of_Values_and_Many%282D%29To%282D%29Many_Associations) mapping to achieve this. Are you using XML or fluent mapping?